# Postgres - decode special characters

Tags: postgresql

I have words like this encoded: "cizaña", the encoded result is 63697A61F161

When I try to convert to 'cizaña' again

```
select decode('63697A61F161'::text, 'hex')
```

I get:

```
"ciza\361a"
```

What can I do? I tried to set `set client_encoding to 'UTF-8';` without luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the encoded result is 63697A61F161

"encoded" how? I think you care confusing text encoding with representation format of binary data.

`63697A61F161` is the iso-8859-1 ("latin-1") encoding of the text "cizaña" with the binary represetned as hex octets.

`decode('63697A61F161', 'hex')` produces the bytea value `'\x63697A61F161`' if `bytea_encoding` is `hex` or `'ciza\361a'` if `bytea_encoding` is `escape`. Either way, it's a representation of a binary string, not text.

If you want *text*, you must *decode the text encoding* into the current database text encoding with `convert_from`, e.g.

```
test=> select convert_from(decode('63697A61F161', 'hex'), 'iso-8859-1');
 convert_from 
--------------
 cizaña
(1 row)
```

This should help explain:

```
demo=> select convert_from(BYTEA 'ciza\361a', 'iso-8859-1');
 convert_from 
--------------
 cizaña
(1 row)
```

See? `'ciza\361a'` is an octal-escape representation of the binary data for the iso-8859-1 encoding of the text 'cizaña'. It's the exact same value as the bytea hex-format value `'\x63697A61F161'`:

```
demo=> select convert_from(BYTEA '\x63697A61F161', 'iso-8859-1');
 convert_from 
--------------
 cizaña
(1 row)
```

So:

`decode` and `encode` transform text-string representations of binary data to and from `bytea` literals, Postgres binary objects. Which are output in a text form for display.h The encoding/decoding here is one of binary representation e.g. hex or base64.

`convert_from` and `convert_to` take binary data and apply text encoding processing to convert it to or from the local native database text encoding, producing text strings. The encoding here is text encoding.

It's ... not easy to follow at first. You might have to learn more about text encodings.